# Code run well in a single line but not in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

When I run the code

```
echo "linux.com ,"  $(dig +short ns linux.com | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $0}')
```

Result

```
linux.com , ns1.dnsimple.com., ns2.dnsimple.com., ns3.dnsimple.com., ns4.dnsimple.com.
```

When I run in a loop it won't work, please suggest

```
#!/bin/bash
#/fullpath/dns.sh
#finding DNS of all websites 

yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)


while IFS= read -r line

do

echo "$line,"  $(dig +short ns $line | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $0}') >>  $yesterday.csv

done < /fullpath/domains.csv
```

It give me only domains list

```
000caua5456aod4das98dcp10ad0456a0xa.club
,
007hertz.com
,
0086sp.com
,
00q198.com
,
```

domains.csv file

```
000caua5456aod4das98dcp10ad0456a0xa.club
007hertz.com
0086sp.com
00q198.com
```

---

Edited

> what I understand its reading $line with an "enter" (with a new line)

Comment: I get a different output in `2020-04-25.csv`: https://pastebin.com/raw/bNHmXTjZ

Comment: It's odd that, in your output, the comma is showing up on a separate line from the domain itself. Is it possible that domains.csv has some weird character at the end of each line?

Comment: @Cor Omnes I get the expected output with your script. If the CSV is formatted for windows (`\r\n` line endings) then I get bad results, but different from yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `/fullpath/domains.csv` comes with DOS format, so you can fix this with IFS:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/fullpath/dns.sh
#finding DNS of all websites 

yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)


while IFS=$'\r'"$IFS" read -r line
do
    echo "$line,"  $(dig +short ns "$line" | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $0}') >>  $yesterday.csv
done < /fullpath/domains.csv
```

Alternatively, you can do `dos2unix /fullpath/domains.csv` before running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Works with adding missing double quotes:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)


while IFS= read -r line

do

echo "$line,"  "$(dig +short ns "$line" | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print $0}')" 

done < /fullpath/domains.csv > "$yesterday.csv"
```

Alternatively to your script:

```sh
xargs -l1 -c 'set -- "$0" $(dig +short ns "$0"); IFS=,; echo "$*"' </fullpath/domains.csv sh >"$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F).csv"
```

Comment: I use the double quote, but it's producing the same result ...